# how to fill in html textbox from (c# ) windows application

Tags: c#, javascript, windows

I would like to do the following from a windows application:

1. Open a browser and navigate to a URL.
2. When i am at the correct URL in my browser window, i want to fill in data in the html textboxes on that page from my windows application.
3. When that is done i want to press a button.

Note:
Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox is currently used in my browser Window.
Internet Explorer(IE) is not used in browser Window.

1.The URL (https://www.exple.com/login.html ) had already opened on anyone web browsers such as Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome in local System.
It consists of Two Textboxes such as Username and Password .

2.I Want to fill in data in Username & Password Textbox on Google Chrome/Mozilla Firefox Web Browser.

3.The Input data is taken from C# Windows Application to URL When pressed Submit Button in Windows Application.

Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 1):

That's what [WatiN](http://watin.org/) is for. It was primarily created for web application testing, but your problem can be solved with WatiN as well.

Example from the front page:

```
[Test] 
public void SearchForWatiNOnGoogle()
{
    using (var browser = new IE("http://www.google.com"))
    {
        browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");
        browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();

        Assert.IsTrue(browser.ContainsText("WatiN"));
    }
}
```

This example uses IE, but Firefox is supported as well.

Comment: asking about Mozilla Firefox/Google Chrome Web Browser

Comment: @mrlingam Mozilla Firefox is supported, as I have already said.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but it will really hard,but if you make autoscript in [testcomplete](http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/automated-testing-tools) and then get code from it, code will be ugly , but working